# How can I use multiple inheritance in case of manipulating variable value

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

```
class Electronicdevice():
    Devices = 100
class Pocketgadgets(Electronicdevice):
    Pocketdevices = 40
class Phone(Pocketgadgets):
    #Phones = Devices - Pocketdevices
    pass

Samsung = Electronicdevice()
Galaxy = Pocketgadgets()
SamsungGalaxyS21 = Phone()

print(SamsungGalaxyS21.Devices)
```

I get the expected output in this case as 100, since it inherits the value from the Electronic device class.

But in case , I try to do the below ,I get an error "NameError: name 'Devices' is not defined"

```
class Electronicdevice():
    Devices = 100
class Pocketgadgets(Electronicdevice):
    Pocketdevices = 40
class Phone(Pocketgadgets):
    Phones = Devices - Pocketdevices
    pass

Samsung = Electronicdevice()
Galaxy = Pocketgadgets()
SamsungGalaxyS21 = Phone()

print(SamsungGalaxyS21.Phones)
```

Was expecting to get the value 60 as output.Can someone please help?

Comment: `Devices` is not in scope in `Phone`, you must use `Electronicdevice.Devices` (or `PocketGadgets.Devices`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try these solutions:

Solution 1:
Access the `variables` through the `class`

```py
class Electronicdevice:
    Devices = 100


class Pocketgadgets(Electronicdevice):
    Pocketdevices = 40


class Phone(Pocketgadgets):
    Phones = Electronicdevice.Devices - Pocketgadgets.Pocketdevices


Samsung = Electronicdevice()
Galaxy = Pocketgadgets()
SamsungGalaxyS21 = Phone()

print(SamsungGalaxyS21.Phones)
```

```sh
60
```

`NB: this example is independent of the inheritance, that is, even if you don't inherit from **Pocketgadgets** class, it will still work.`

Solution 2:
Access the `variables` through an `instance` of the `class`

```py
class Electronicdevice:
    Devices = 100


class Pocketgadgets(Electronicdevice):
    Pocketdevices = 40


class Phone(Pocketgadgets):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Phones = self.Devices - self.Pocketdevices


Samsung = Electronicdevice()
Galaxy = Pocketgadgets()
SamsungGalaxyS21 = Phone()

print(SamsungGalaxyS21.Phones)
```

```sh
60
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
But doesn't inheritance increase the scope of variable? @Daniel

Comment: yeah, it increases the scope but `class variables` are bound to the `class` and can only be accessed through the `class` or an `instance` of the `class`. `NB: with the first example, it is independent of the inheritance, that is, even you don't inherit from **Pocketgadgets** class, it will still work.`